# php - how to prevent echo &macr creates ¯ character,

Tags: php, html, string, url, character

I want to echo a string of an url variable:

```
echo "direct=1&closeBrowser=1&savelog=log.txt&storage=xfile&macrfile=klanta\test.html";
```

except the '&macr' creates the ¯ characters. How do i prevent this from happening?

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars($your_string);`

Comment: the `"` will also cause the T in Test to be escaped aswell. either double up on your back slash or use `'` instead

Comment: Since you've stated that string is URL parameters you might want `rawurlencode()` instead of `htmlspecialchars()` - it depends on what you're doing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htmlspecialchars function is used to convert special characters to HTML entities. See for reference, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

You can use this code :

```
$str = direct=1&closeBrowser=1&savelog=log.txt&storage=xfile&macrfile=klanta\test.html
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

OR you can use regular Expression :

```
echo preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -]/s','', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a strings as raw text (ignoring any html special entities or tags), then use function `htmlspecialchars($string)`.

Example:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($your_string);
```

Details: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php